# Is it possible to verify if Automatic1111 is addressing all available VRAM in a multi GPU environment?

Tags: automatic1111-sd-web-ui

In a multi-GPU environment - for example when using it in conjunction with a rendering farm mounting 4+ graphics cards - is there any mechanism to confirm if Automatic1111 (any stable version) is addressing the full range of available VRAM on all of the available cards, or if it is only addressing the VRAM on the first available card?

Comment: Do you have ways to measure the used VRAM on the system while your tool is running? Here is an [answer for NVidia GPUs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38581/50687) at unix.SE, some other answers mention AMD and Intel.